# How to create this inset effect on text?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm new to Adobe Illustrator and am having a hard time getting text to have this kind of inset look. I see that the top right of the text edges contains a shadow and the bottom left contains the highlights.

[image: Inset logo text]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like a Photoshop Bevel and Emboss, set to pillow emboss with an additional inner shadow to me. In other words, I'm not certain the image you posted is an Illustrator-generated image at all.

You can do this in Illustrator, however, it's not as easy as ticking and adjusting a few Layer Style options. You customarily need to *create* actual objects for the highlights and shadows.

[image]

Right-click the image and choose "Open Image in New Window/Tab" to see it larger.

(I masked some of the Transform effect window.. the other options can all be left at their default settings.)

The gist is (in case images don't load)...

- Add a new white fill via Appearance panel, move it below the base fill, then use `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` to move the white fill slightly downward.
- Then add a black fill via the Appearance Panel below the base fill and use `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` to move the black fill slightly upward.
- On the base fill add `Effect > Stylize > Inner Glow` set to black and Multiply to create an inner shadow effect.

You can further refine as needed, but these are the basic steps.

For further refinement, you can use the Pathfinder commands to create additional (separate) objects to indicate shadows, and a slight gradient on the base fill helps as well....

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Side note - What program are you using to draw the arrows and boxes?

Comment: I open screenshots in Photoshop to combine and add notes. They are manually added, nothing automated.